# Four whitish screens whenever I try to install a Linux distro

Tags: linux, boot

I have been trying to install linux for the past few days on my 2010 iMac, I completely wiped off OS X so I could have the entire HDD space for linux.
However, this happens whenever I boot a distro from my usb.

[image]

I have no idea why this happens since I'm pretty much new to Linux.
I tried many distros and all of these led to the same problem:

- Kubuntu
- Linux Mint
- Xubuntu (In the picture)
- OpenSUSE
- Archlinux
- Korora
- Elementary OS

However this problem does not occur with Debian, although I'm not exactly sure about using Debian for home use.
Does anyone have any idea about what's going on?

Comment: No idea what is going on, by why not install Debian. You can put Cinnamon on top of that if the UI is what keeps you back.

Answer (score 1):

If it's only the white screen and it's not present in Debian, it will be about the drivers. What I'd do is to install the OS you want most with this white screen and then load the right graphic drivers. If they're not there, there's not much you can do apart from coding them yourselfs. So best while taking the decision about which one to choose, check if it supports your hardware, if that's not too difficult for you.

(Why wouldn't be Debian right for home use, btw? It's the easiest option you have at the moment.)